# discord.js Getting the URL Of Canvas Attachment

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get the URL of the attachment and send it to a channel , I tried to use `attachment.url` but but I'm getting `undefined`
here is my code:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {

            if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
            if (message.content.toLowerCase().indexOf(prefix.toLowerCase()) !== 0) return;
            var args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
            var command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

            if(command =='image'){
            let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(' ');
            const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(400, 140);
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
         
     
                ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
                ctx.font = '150px serif';
                ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
                ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
                ctx.fillText(`${args}`, 0, 118);
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
                ctx.strokeText(`${args}`, -1, 118);
                ctx.textAlign = "center";
               
               const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'image.png')
               
        message.channel.send(`\`${attachment.url}\``)
        }})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed only get the Discord URL of an attachment **after** sending it. An easy way to grab it would be using `async/await`:

```
client.on('message', async message => {

  if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().indexOf(prefix.toLowerCase()) !== 0) return;
  var args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  var command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'image') {
    const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(400, 140);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.font = '150px serif';
    ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
    ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
    ctx.fillText(`${args}`, 0, 118);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.strokeText(`${args}`, -1, 118);
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
     
    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'image.png');
     
    const reply = await message.channel.send({ files: [attachment] });
    const attachmentURL = reply.attachments.first().url;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you aren't able to get the url of it before it has been sent, you would need to send the attachment first before attempting to get its url.